# Xcode not opening and question mark on ios simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, macos

**When I am trying to open xcode then it gives me an error**

**For your kind information I am working on Flutter**

Xcode error screenshot:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfAjQ.jpg)

Xcode full error:-

```
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               Xcode [987]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               13.4.1 (20504)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-20504000000000000~2 (13F100)
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       849405240
Code Type:             ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2022-07-05 20:18:29.6652 +0600
OS Version:            macOS 12.4 (21F79)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        BFC37DE6-5667-DA64-D362-1D0670B53487


Time Awake Since Boot: 420 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
abort() called


Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1b01c2d98 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1b01f7ee0 pthread_kill + 288
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x1b0132340 abort + 168
3   Xcode                                  0x1042ff4c4 main.cold.1 + 40
4   Xcode                                  0x1042febd0 main + 356
5   dyld                                   0x1045ed08c start + 520


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x000000004b010001   x5: 0x0000000000000001   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x13f54261f51d14cd   x9: 0x13f54260f17b114d  x10: 0x007ffffffffffff8  x11: 0x00000003f2f7001a
   x12: 0x000000000000000a  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x00000001afecc000  x15: 0x000000026ad98000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x000000020a283680  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000104660580  x21: 0x0000000000000103  x22: 0x0000000104660660  x23: 0x0000000144806260
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000000000000  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x000000016bb03940   lr: 0x00000001b01f7ee0
    sp: 0x000000016bb03920   pc: 0x00000001b01c2d98 cpsr: 0x40001000
   far: 0x0000000142f28050  esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault

Binary Images:
       0x1b01b9000 -        0x1b01f0fff libsystem_kernel.dylib (*) <03f48dc5-caa7-3678-af61-1a3c7fa8b06e> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
       0x1b01f1000 -        0x1b01fdfff libsystem_pthread.dylib (*) <42166a2c-89a9-3c38-a215-f028544cea23> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
       0x1b00b8000 -        0x1b0139fff libsystem_c.dylib (*) <86746b94-88e3-342d-b2b2-54303404e492> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
       0x1042fc000 -        0x1042fffff com.apple.dt.Xcode (13.4.1) <209ad0d0-251b-3efc-a3ea-fd175763be79> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
       0x1045e8000 -        0x104647fff dyld (*) <d9c2a46e-8dc4-3950-9d6a-f799e8ccb683> /usr/lib/dyld

External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

VM Region Summary:
ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=817.4M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=817.4M(100%)
Writable regions: Total=163.1M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=163.1M(100%)

                                VIRTUAL   REGION 
REGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) 
===========                     =======  ======= 
Kernel Alloc Once                   32K        1 
MALLOC                            35.1M       13 
MALLOC guard page                   96K        5 
MALLOC_MEDIUM (reserved)         120.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)
STACK GUARD                       56.0M        1 
Stack                             8176K        1 
__AUTH                            1863K      147 
__AUTH_CONST                      10.2M      292 
__DATA                            8604K      279 
__DATA_CONST                      10.2M      296 
__DATA_DIRTY                       806K      111 
__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 
__LINKEDIT                       577.3M        3 
__OBJC_CONST                      1357K      114 
__OBJC_RO                         83.0M        1 
__OBJC_RW                         3152K        1 
__TEXT                           240.1M      309 
__UNICODE                          592K        1 
dyld private memory               1024K        1 
shared memory                       16K        1 
===========                     =======  ======= 
TOTAL                              1.1G     1579 
TOTAL, minus reserved VM space     1.0G     1579 



-----------
Full Report
-----------

{"app_name":"Xcode","timestamp":"2022-07-05 20:18:31.00 +0600","app_version":"13.4.1","slice_uuid":"209ad0d0-251b-3efc-a3ea-fd175763be79","adam_id":"497799835","build_version":"20504","platform":1,"bundleID":"com.apple.dt.Xcode","share_with_app_devs":1,"is_first_party":0,"bug_type":"309","os_version":"macOS 12.4 (21F79)","incident_id":"9321D790-BA4A-4748-9B50-681A237C3F19","name":"Xcode"}
{
  "uptime" : 420,
  "procLaunch" : "2022-07-05 20:18:24.3525 +0600",
  "procRole" : "Background",
  "version" : 2,
  "userID" : 501,
  "deployVersion" : 210,
  "modelCode" : "MacBookAir10,1",
  "procStartAbsTime" : 10082599645,
  "coalitionID" : 995,
  "osVersion" : {
    "train" : "macOS 12.4",
    "build" : "21F79",
    "releaseType" : "User"
  },
  "captureTime" : "2022-07-05 20:18:29.6652 +0600",
  "incident" : "9321D790-BA4A-4748-9B50-681A237C3F19",
  "bug_type" : "309",
  "pid" : 987,
  "procExitAbsTime" : 10210035128,
  "translated" : false,
  "cpuType" : "ARM-64",
  "procName" : "Xcode",
  "procPath" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/MacOS\/Xcode",
  "bundleInfo" : {"CFBundleShortVersionString":"13.4.1","CFBundleVersion":"20504","CFBundleIdentifier":"com.apple.dt.Xcode"},
  "buildInfo" : {"ProjectName":"IDEFrameworks","SourceVersion":"20504000000000000","ProductBuildVersion":"13F100","BuildVersion":"2"},
  "storeInfo" : {"storeCohortMetadata":"10|date=1656723600000&sf=143441&pgtp=Software&pgid=497799835&prpg=Search_osx&ctxt=Search&issrch=1&lngid=1","itemID":"497799835","deviceIdentifierForVendor":"6C4FDE9F-1F16-5026-ADB9-A87FF85DC63E","thirdParty":true,"softwareVersionExternalIdentifier":"849405240"},
  "parentProc" : "launchd",
  "parentPid" : 1,
  "coalitionName" : "com.apple.dt.Xcode",
  "crashReporterKey" : "BFC37DE6-5667-DA64-D362-1D0670B53487",
  "sip" : "enabled",
  "isCorpse" : 1,
  "exception" : {"codes":"0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000","rawCodes":[0,0],"type":"EXC_CRASH","signal":"SIGABRT"},
  "asi" : {"libsystem_c.dylib":["abort() called"]},
  "extMods" : {"caller":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"system":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"targeted":{"thread_create":0,"thread_set_state":0,"task_for_pid":0},"warnings":0},
  "faultingThread" : 0,
  "threads" : [{"triggered":true,"id":11247,"threadState":{"x":[{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":1258356737},{"value":1},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":1438128644506326221},{"value":1438128640150409549},{"value":36028797018963960},{"value":16961175578},{"value":10},{"value":0},{"value":7246495744},{"value":10382573568},{"value":328},{"value":8760342144},{"value":0},{"value":6},{"value":4368762240,"symbolLocation":0,"symbol":"_main_thread"},{"value":259},{"value":4368762464,"symbolLocation":224,"symbol":"_main_thread"},{"value":5444231776},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}],"flavor":"ARM_THREAD_STATE64","lr":{"value":7249821408},"cpsr":{"value":1073745920},"fp":{"value":6101678400},"sp":{"value":6101678368},"esr":{"value":1442840704,"description":" Address size fault"},"pc":{"value":7249603992,"matchesCrashFrame":1},"far":{"value":5418156112}},"queue":"com.apple.main-thread","frames":[{"imageOffset":40344,"symbol":"__pthread_kill","symbolLocation":8,"imageIndex":0},{"imageOffset":28384,"symbol":"pthread_kill","symbolLocation":288,"imageIndex":1},{"imageOffset":500544,"symbol":"abort","symbolLocation":168,"imageIndex":2},{"imageOffset":13508,"symbol":"main.cold.1","symbolLocation":40,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":11216,"symbol":"main","symbolLocation":356,"imageIndex":3},{"imageOffset":20620,"symbol":"start","symbolLocation":520,"imageIndex":4}]}],
  "usedImages" : [
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7249563648,
    "size" : 229376,
    "uuid" : "03f48dc5-caa7-3678-af61-1a3c7fa8b06e",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_kernel.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_kernel.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7249793024,
    "size" : 53248,
    "uuid" : "42166a2c-89a9-3c38-a215-f028544cea23",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_pthread.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_pthread.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 7248510976,
    "size" : 532480,
    "uuid" : "86746b94-88e3-342d-b2b2-54303404e492",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_c.dylib",
    "name" : "libsystem_c.dylib"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64",
    "base" : 4365205504,
    "CFBundleShortVersionString" : "13.4.1",
    "CFBundleIdentifier" : "com.apple.dt.Xcode",
    "size" : 16384,
    "uuid" : "209ad0d0-251b-3efc-a3ea-fd175763be79",
    "path" : "\/Applications\/Xcode.app\/Contents\/MacOS\/Xcode",
    "name" : "Xcode",
    "CFBundleVersion" : "20504"
  },
  {
    "source" : "P",
    "arch" : "arm64e",
    "base" : 4368269312,
    "size" : 393216,
    "uuid" : "d9c2a46e-8dc4-3950-9d6a-f799e8ccb683",
    "path" : "\/usr\/lib\/dyld",
    "name" : "dyld"
  }
],
  "sharedCache" : {
  "base" : 7246495744,
  "size" : 3136077824,
  "uuid" : "513553bb-5ca5-3b9e-a613-b0603ffe3038"
},
  "vmSummary" : "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=817.4M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=817.4M(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=163.1M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=163.1M(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nKernel Alloc Once                   32K        1 \nMALLOC                            35.1M       13 \nMALLOC guard page                   96K        5 \nMALLOC_MEDIUM (reserved)         120.0M        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)\nSTACK GUARD                       56.0M        1 \nStack                             8176K        1 \n__AUTH                            1863K      147 \n__AUTH_CONST                      10.2M      292 \n__DATA                            8604K      279 \n__DATA_CONST                      10.2M      296 \n__DATA_DIRTY                       806K      111 \n__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 \n__LINKEDIT                       577.3M        3 \n__OBJC_CONST                      1357K      114 \n__OBJC_RO                         83.0M        1 \n__OBJC_RW                         3152K        1 \n__TEXT                           240.1M      309 \n__UNICODE                          592K        1 \ndyld private memory               1024K        1 \nshared memory                       16K        1 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                              1.1G     1579 \nTOTAL, minus reserved VM space     1.0G     1579 \n",
  "legacyInfo" : {
  "threadTriggered" : {
    "queue" : "com.apple.main-thread"
  }
},
  "trialInfo" : {
  "rollouts" : [
    {
      "rolloutId" : "5ffde50ce2aacd000d47a95f",
      "factorPackIds" : {

      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000167
    },
    {
      "rolloutId" : "61301e3a61217b3110231469",
      "factorPackIds" : {
        "SIRI_FIND_MY_CONFIGURATION_FILES" : "6216ae152a40e71046e16225"
      },
      "deploymentId" : 240000016
    }
  ],
  "experiments" : [

  ]
}
}

Model: MacBookAir10,1, BootROM 7459.121.3, proc 8:4:4 processors, 8 GB, SMC 
Graphics: Apple M1, Apple M1, Built-In
Display: Color LCD, 2560 x 1600 Retina, Main, MirrorOff, Online
Memory Module: LPDDR4
AirPort: Wi-Fi, wl0: Mar 23 2022 19:57:59 version 18.60.27.0.7.8.129 FWID 01-570be953
Bluetooth: Version (null), 0 services, 0 devices, 0 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
USB Device: USB31Bus
USB Device: USB31Bus
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc.
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Air, Apple Inc.
```

Question mark and not opening ios simulator screenshot:-
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDD4V.png)

**All working perfectly. When I was installed xcode command line tools through system update and then I was installed homebrew and install cocoapods through brew. Then my problem starts.**

I am begineer in this field. Thats why please look at it with an apologetic look.

Comment: are you opening Xcode directly or from the xcworkspace file?

Answer (score 0):

Question mark appears when the app is not found
In your case Question mark is showing on Simulator which means Xcode is unable to fetch your IOS Simulator

Solution: Remove Caches from your Xcode and remove all older created IOS simulator and try creating new one with updated at IOS 15.5